# Bluemix push notification service - The use of App Route parameter is deprecated

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

Seems like the Bluemix Push Notification service has been subject to changes recently. Indeed, when you click on the **Mobile Options** button in the configuration panel, a message in the pop up window states that `The use of App Route parameter is deprecated`.

However, this app route parameter was required when intializing the BMSClient plugin (`BMSClient.initialize(BLUEMIX_PUSH_APP_ROUTE, BLUEMIX_PUSH_APP_GUID)`)

What is the right way to initialize the ibm-mfp-push plugin now that the app route parameter is deprecated?

I know that the `ibm-mfp-mush` cordova plugin is currently being updated. Will the update address that issue? Is there a status about the release of the updated version of the plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So for the time being, continue to use your regular app route (from the MobileFirstServices starter or other).

The new `ibm-mfp-push` (probably will be renamed `bms-push`) will address this issue. It is currently in the backlog. The estimated time of completion is about one month from now.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your answer. The thing is I had to create a new instance of the Bluemix Push service, and it did not have an app route config property. I ended up using **https://mobile.eu-gb.bluemix.net** which seems to work properly

Comment: The new `bms-push` plugin has released, so the App Route is no longer a required parameter.